# Error al ejecutar un JAR de NetBeans

Tags: java, firebase, netbeans, maven, google-cloud-firestore

Tengo el siguiente error al intenta ejecutar con el comando **java -jar** una de mis aplicaciones hecha en NetBeans.
Estoy corriendo el JAR desde cmd para poder ver el error que me sale

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es una aplicación que funciona con Firebase, ya implemente el LoadBalancerProvider que forma parte de io.grpc y otras dependencias de la misma, pero me sigue apareciendo el mismo error.

Dejo las dependencias de mi pom.xml

`````
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-admin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>AbsoluteLayout</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE160</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-firestore -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-firestore</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.formdev/flatlaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.formdev</groupId>
            <artifactId>flatlaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>1.53.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>1.53.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>1.53.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.53.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>````
`````